# Lookup dictionary instead of function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am pretty new to python and use it only for data analysis.

I got this function to look up specific parameters based on a category and a conditions. I have the idea that this can be done more elegantly. Probably with a dictionary, but I couldn't figure out how to make the `x < x1`  aspect work

What would be the best way to do this?

```
def stab_class_z(x,cl):
    # Get the sigma_z parameters for each stability class and the distance
    if cl == "A":
        if x < 0.1:
            a = 122.8
            b = 0.9447
        elif x < 0.16:
            a = 158.08
            b = 1.0542
        elif x < 0.21:
            a = 170.22
            b = 1.0932
        elif x < 0.26:
            a = 179.52
            b = 1.1262
        elif x < 0.31:
            a = 217.41
            b = 1.2644
        elif x < 0.41:
            a = 258.89
            b = 1.4094
        elif x < 0.51:
            a = 346.75
            b = 1.7283
        elif x <= 3.11:
            a = 453.85
            b = 2.11660
        else:
            print("not defined________")
    if cl == "B":
        if x < 0.2:
            a = 90.673
            b = 0.93198
        elif x <= 0.4:
            a = 98.483
            b = 0.98332
        else:
            a = 109.3
            b = 1.0971
# And so it continues for cl: 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
    return a,b
```

Comment: You can't directly access a key with "lower than" logic; at best you can make a dict like `{0.1: (122.8, 0.9447), ...}`, and then iterate each key and test it with `<` to find the right key. Might be *slightly* more elegant, but not fundamentally.

Answer (score -1):

Yes for sure a dictionary can be used here.

First of all your dictionary keys can be your cl parameter. Then your can use tuple as key for your dictionary.

You could do something like the following (maybe not optimal)

```py
stab_class_dict = { 'A' : {(0,0.1):(122.8,0.9457), (0.1,0.16): (158.08,1.0542)}}

def stab_class_z(x: float, cl: str):
    for limit in stab_class_dict[cl]:
        if limit[0] <= x < limit[1]:
            return stab_class_dict[cl][limit] 
    return (default_value_a, default_value_b)
```

Of course be careful that cl is indeed a key of stab_class_dict.

Comment: default_value_a and default_value_b aren't defined

Comment: Dicts are meant to be accessed directly by keys so that one can benefit from its *O(1)* time complexity in member lookups. By iterating over the keys of a dict your code defeats the purpose of a dict, and might as well use a list of tuples instead.

Comment: I know that default_value are not defined but I am not the question owner so I don't know which default value are supposed to be ...
And as for the problem is defined then iterating over the value of the interval seems to me the best way but maybe you have another solution ?